# Django Table 2 - get column content

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

i'm trying to do something like:

```
if filed_1:
  field_1 = tables.LinkColumn('fields:detail', args=[A('field_1')])
else:
  field_2 = tables.LinkColumn('fields:detail', args=[A('field_2')])
```

if the table contains data in field_1 then field_1 must be a link column else field_2 is a link column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [templatecolumn](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#django_tables2.columns.TemplateColumn):

```
titol = tables.TemplateColumn(
                    template_code = u"""
                             {% if record.filed_1 %}
                             <a href={% url 'fields:detail' record.field_1.pk %}>
                             {{record.field_1}}</a>
                             {% else %}
                             <a href={% url 'fields:detail' record.field_2.pk %}>
                             {{record.field_2}}</a>
                             {% endif %}
                                    """ , 
                    verbose_name= u"field",  
                    order_by=( 'field_1', 'field_2' )
                               )
```